How to restrict Emmet suggestions to only JSX code in `javascriptreact` files in VS Code?
I'm using Visual Studio Code for React development and I want Emmet suggestions to appear only when I'm writing JSX code, not regular JavaScript, in javascriptreact files (.js, .ts, .jsx or .tsx).
Issue I'm facing:
See this image to see my actual problem
I don't want to see the Emmet abbreviation while writing javascript, because there is no any use of it and it just increasing my worktime.
Despite configuring my settings.json like this:
{
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascriptreact": "html"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
}

I still get Emmet suggestions while writing JavaScript code.
Is there a way to restrict Emmet suggestions to only JSX parts of javascriptreact files in VS Code? Any tips or additional configurations would be greatly appreciated.
